# Count query take much time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have i have 61K rows in my database `mysql` and I try to make a count but the query take 4 seconds and i think it's too much.

```
select count( distinct appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) 
from ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_ 
inner join ao.lot lots1_ on appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lots1_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE 
inner join ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut2_ on appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lieuexecut2_.appel_offre 
inner join ao.acheteur acheteur3_ on appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR=acheteur3_.ID_ACHETEUR 
inner join ao.ao_activite aoactivite4_ on appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=aoactivite4_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
```

my query result :

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| count( distinct appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                        61100 |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (4.35 sec)
```

why in `explain` cmd table `appeloffre0_` use key `appel_offre_ibfk_2` which is a index on FK column `ID_ACHETEUR` ?

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appeloffre0_ | index  | PRIMARY,appel_offre_ibfk_2 | appel_offre_ibfk_2 | 4       | NULL                           | 60031 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acheteur3_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY            | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR    |     1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lieuexecut2_ | ref    | fk_ao_lieuex               | fk_ao_lieuex       | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE |     1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | aoactivite4_ | ref    | ao_activites_ao_fk         | ao_activites_ao_fk | 4       | ao.lieuexecut2_.appel_offre    |     3 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lots1_       | ref    | FK_LOT_AO                  | FK_LOT_AO          | 4       | ao.lieuexecut2_.appel_offre    |     5 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

show index from appel_offre

```
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| appel_offre |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | ID_APPEL_OFFRE      | A         |       60953 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_1 |            1 | ID_APPEL_OFFRE_MERE | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_2 |            1 | ID_ACHETEUR         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_3 |            1 | USER_SAISIE         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_4 |            1 | USER_VALIDATION     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | ao_fk_3            |            1 | TYPE_MARCHE         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | ao_fk_5            |            1 | USER_CONTROLE       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

1. how can i use index to run fast count query ?
2. how to use index when we have multiple join ?
3. how to use index when we have multiple join and multiple search
   query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `distinct` in your count try replacing your 1 to many inner joins with `exists` conditions.

For example, if `lot.ID_APPEL_OFFRE` is not unique, then remove the inner join

```
inner join ao.lot lots1_ on appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lots1_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
```

and add an exists condition in your where clause

```
where exists (select 1 from ao.lot lots_1 where appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lots1_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE)
```

Comment: thanks @FuzzyTree it reduce my time to 0.7s, can u answer my 2 and 3 point ? because i will use a multi criteria search with multiple join. you can give me a good tuto if you can.

Comment: @Youssef according to your explain output it looks like you are already using indexes correctly with your multiple join / where criteria

Comment: it seems that after adding some where clause it took time again check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784778/slow-count-query-with-where-clause