# Slow count query with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a count to get the total number of results in a pagination but the query is too slow **2.12s**

```
+-------+
| size  |
+-------+
| 50000 |
+-------+
1 row in set (2.12 sec)
```

my count query

```
select  count(appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) as size  
from  ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_  
inner join ao.acheteur acheteur1_ 
on appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR=acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR 
where 
(exists (select 1 from ao.lot lot2_ where lot2_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE and lot2_.ESTIMATION_COUT>=1)) 
and (exists (select 1 from ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut3_ where lieuexecut3_.appel_offre=appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE and lieuexecut3_.region=1)) 
and (exists (select 1 from ao.ao_activite aoactivite4_ where aoactivite4_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE and (aoactivite4_.ID_ACTIVITE=1))) 
and appeloffre0_.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS>'2015-01-01' 
and (appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='fournitures' or appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='travaux' or appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='services') 
and acheteur1_.ID_ENTITE_MERE=2
```

explain cmd :

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type | possible_keys                               | key                | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | acheteur1_   | ref  | PRIMARY,acheteur_ibfk_1                     | acheteur_ibfk_1    | 5       | const                          |     3 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | appeloffre0_ | ref  | appel_offre_ibfk_2                          | appel_offre_ibfk_2 | 4       | ao.acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR      | 31061 | Using where              |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | aoactivite4_ | ref  | ao_activites_activite_fk,ao_activites_ao_fk | ao_activites_ao_fk | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE |     3 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lieuexecut3_ | ref  | fk_ao_lieuex,fk_region_lieuex               | fk_ao_lieuex       | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE |     1 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | lot2_        | ref  | FK_LOT_AO                                   | FK_LOT_AO          | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE |     5 | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

the index `acheteur_ibfk_1` is a FK references table `ENTITE_MERE` because i have and `acheteur1_.ID_ENTITE_MERE=2` in where clause.

Comment: Couldn't you replace those subqueries with joins?

Comment: it seems that with sub-queries is better but i didn't add where clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761649/count-query-take-much-time

Comment: "where exists" logic is slow...much better to join subqueries than to use where exists

Comment: can u give me example to to join subqueries ?

Comment: You might also want to make sure that everything is indexed properly: [MySQL Documentation: Optimisation and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: I'm confused where @DanBracuk and @Twelfth are coming from. `WHERE EXISTS` *is* a join when correctly written.  It should perform identically.

Comment: Try creating a composite index on `appel_offre (CATEGORIE,DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS)` `DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS` should be last because it's an inequality. P.S: `exists` is faster than an inner join if it's not a 1:1 relationship because it terminates as soon as it finds 1 whereas the join will get every matching row. on top of that you don't have the overhead of `distinct`

Comment: @FuzzyTree i update my answer and it seems that `IN` works faster than `exists` :-) can explain me why ?

Comment: Like others have said, the bottleneck in your query is the lack of an appropriate key: in the 'explain' output, all keys but one would ideally return exactly 1 row. Try @FuzzyTree's advice and give some thought to your table design and relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @FuzzyTree said in his comment `exists` is faster than an inner join if it's not a 1:1 relationship because it terminates as soon as it finds 1 whereas the join will get every matching row.

But the solution is that We add `in` and not `exists`  :

```
where ( appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE IN (select lot2_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE from ao.lot lot2_  
             where    lot2_.ESTIMATION_COUT>=1)
      )
```

So the query run very fast than exists or joins .

```
select  count(appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) as size  
from  ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_  
inner join ao.acheteur acheteur1_ 
on appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR=acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR 
where 
( appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE IN (select lot2_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE from ao.lot lot2_  where    lot2_.ESTIMATION_COUT>=1)) 
and (appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE IN (select lieuexecut3_.appel_offre from ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut3_  where  lieuexecut3_.region=1)) 
and (appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE IN (select aoactivite4_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE from ao.ao_activite aoactivite4_  where aoactivite4_.ID_ACTIVITE=1 )) 
and appeloffre0_.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS>'2015-01-01' 
and (appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='fournitures' or appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='travaux' or appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='services') 
and acheteur1_.ID_ENTITE_MERE=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple conditions on your [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) by using ON condition1 AND condition2 etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) as size  
FROM  ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_  
JOIN ao.acheteur acheteur1_ ON appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR=acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR 
JOIN ao.lot lot2_ ON appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lot2_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE AND lot2_.ESTIMATION_COUT>=1 
JOIN ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut3_ ON appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lieuexecut3_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE AND lieuexecut3_.ID_ACTIVITE=1
JOIN ao.ao_activite aoactivite4_ ON appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=aoactivite4_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE AND aoactivite4_.ID_ACTIVITE=1
WHERE appeloffre0_.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS>'2015-01-01' 
AND (appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='fournitures' OR appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='travaux' OR appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE='services') 
AND acheteur1_.ID_ENTITE_MERE=2;
```

Comment: thank @Brian unfortunately it took same time but i add a solution you can check it if you can explain me more.

Comment: i update my answer and it seems that `IN` works faster than `exists` and `join`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select count(aa.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) as size  
from  (
select ID_APPEL_OFFRE, ID_ACHETEUR from ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_  
inner join ao.acheteur acheteur1_ 
on appeloffre0_.ID_ACHETEUR=acheteur1_.ID_ACHETEUR 
where appeloffre0_.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS>'2015-01-01' 
and (appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE in ('fournitures','travaux','services')) 
and (acheteur1_.ID_ENTITE_MERE=2)) aa
inner join ao.lot lot2_ on lot2_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=aa.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
inner join ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut3_ on lieuexecut3_.appel_offre=aa.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
inner join ao.ao_activite aoactivite4_  on aoactivite4_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=aa.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
where 
aoactivite4_.ID_ACTIVITE=1
and lot2_.ESTIMATION_COUT>=1
and lieuexecut3_.region=1;
```

But I haven't seen your tables so I am not 100% sure that you won't get duplicates because of joins.

A couple of low-hanging fruits might also be found by ensuring that your appeloffre0_.CATEGORIE and  appeloffre0_.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS have indexes on them.

Other fields which should have indexes on them are ao.lot.ID_APPEL_OFFRE, ao.lieu_execution.ID_APPEL_OFFRE and ao.ao_activite.ID_APPEL_OFFRE, and ao.appel_offre.ID_ACHETEUR (all the joined fields).

Comment: thank @Ashalynd unfortunately it took same time but i add a solution you can check it if you can explain me more.

Comment: i update my answer and it seems that `IN` works faster than `exists` and `join`

Answer (score 1):

I would have the following indexes on your tables if not already...  These are covering indexes for your query meaning the index has the applicable column to get your results without having to go to the actual raw data pages.

```
table           index
appel_offre     ( DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS, CATEGORIE, ID_APPEL_OFFRE, ID_ACHETEUR )
lot             ( ID_APPEL_OFFRE, ESTIMATION_COUT )
lieu_execution  ( appel_offre, region )
ao_activite     ( ID_APPEL_OFFRE, ID_ACTIVITE )
```

Having indexes on just individual columns won't really help optimize what you are looking for.  Also,  I am doing count of DISTINCT ID_APPEL_OFFRE's in case any of the JOINed tables have more than 1 record, it does not create a Cartesian result count for you

```
select  
      count(distinct AOF.ID_APPEL_OFFRE) as size
   from
      ao.appel_offre AOF
         JOIN ao.acheteur ACH
            on AOF.ID_ACHETEUR = ACH.ID_ACHETEUR 
           and ACH.ID_ENTITE_MERE = 2
         JOIN ao.lot
            ON AOF.ID_APPEL_OFFRE = lot.ID_APPEL_OFFRE
           and lot.ESTIMATION_COUT >= 1
         JOIN ao.lieu_execution EX
            ON AOF.ID_APPEL_OFFRE = EX.appel_offre
            and EX.region = 1
         JOIN ao.ao_activite ACT
            ON AOF.ID_APPEL_OFFRE = ACT.ID_APPEL_OFFRE 
           and ACT.ID_ACTIVITE = 1
   where 
          AOF.DATE_OUVERTURE_PLIS > '2015-01-01'
      and (   AOF.CATEGORIE = 'fournitures' 
           or AOF.CATEGORIE = 'travaux' 
           or AOF.CATEGORIE = 'services')
```

Comment: thank @DRapp unfortunately it took same time but i add a solution you can check it if you can explain me more.

Comment: i update my answer and it seems that IN works faster than `exists ` and `join`